# PHP Cookies not being set

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I'm using CodeIgniter to build a webapp for my laws. I'm trying to build a remember me function, but I can't set cookies on either my shared host or locally.

I've tried both CI's cookie helper and PHP's setcookie(), neither work.

PHP:

```
$token = $this->random(32, $this->input->post('userPassword'));
$cookie_value = '{"email":"'. $this->input->post('userEmail') .'","token":"'. $token . '"}';

if ( setcookie('remember_me', urlencode($cookie_value), 1000000, '/') )
{
    echo "Set Val: " . json_encode($cookie_value);
}
```

CI:

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
$token = $this->random(32, $this->input->post('userPassword'));
$cookie_value = '{"email":"'. $this->input->post('userEmail') .'","token":"'. $token . '"}';

if ( set_cookie('remember_me', urlencode($cookie_value), 1000000, '/') )
{
    echo $this->input->cookie('remember_me');
    echo "Set Val: " . json_encode($cookie_value);
}
```

Both seem to work, as they get inside the `if` block, but they don't set the cookie in either Chrome or Firefox.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: wheres the code thats telling you the cookies arent set

Comment: It would likely just be an `else` that `echo "Nope!";`

Comment: How exactly are you determining that the cookies aren't set?

Comment: I'm using Firebug's Cookie inspector and Chromes Resource tab via the Inspector. The `ci_sessions` cookie is being set, so it's something in my code that I'm probably overlooking.

Comment: @Galen In the `if` statement I'm checking to see if the cookie is set and echoing the value. Nothing comes back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, you are setting the expiration of the cookie back in time, so it will expire immediately.

So this:

```
setcookie('remember_me', urlencode($cookie_value), 1000000, '/')
```

Should be:

```
setcookie('remember_me', urlencode($cookie_value), time()+1000000, '/')
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be that simple.